# How to get hungry-delete working in paredit-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, whitespace, paredit

Using [hungry-delete](https://github.com/nflath/hungry-delete) is really nice, see this [Blog post](http://endlessparentheses.com/hungry-delete-mode.html). But with `paredit` activated, `hungry-delete` functions are not triggered.

`paredit` defines `<delete>` as `paredit-forward-delete` and `DEL` as `paredit-backward-delete`, while
`hungry-delete` uses key `<delete>` for `hungry-delete-forward` and `DEL` for `hungry-delete-backward`

How to get `hungry-delete` working in `paredit-mode` with keeping the features of both modes?
(This means the modes should share the `DEL` and `<delete>` key)

Comment: Looking at the source code, I noticed `paredit-backward-delete` calls `backward-delete-char-untabify`, so (instead of using hungry-delete) you can `(setq backward-delete-char-untabify-method 'all)` and to get hungry-delete like behavior from `paredit-backward-delete`. (Notice this only deals with the backward deletion case, it is no help at all for forward deletion.)

Comment: @Omar oh, this is nice. Is there a potential drawback from setting this variable?

Comment: I don't there should be any problem using that variable, @jue, if you look at the documentation you'll see this is what it's meant to be used for. I think of setting it to `all` as the built in alternative to (the backwards half of) hungry delete mode.